# Initialize a class object inside a class object - C++

Tags: c++

How can i initialize a class object from within another class object.

```
class Dummy {
    public:
    Dummy() {}
};
class Server {
    public:
    string ip;
    string port;
    Dummy dummy; // <-- declare an object from within another object.
    public:
    Server(string port__, string ip__, Dummy dummy__) {
        port = port__;
        ip = ip__;
        dummy = dummy__;
    }
    void some_func() {
        // use dummy from here.
        dummy.hello_world();
    }
}
```

And what i want to do is use object Dummy throughout the object Server.

Comment: Are you having any problems doing that?

Comment: You can initialize `dummy` data member in the constructor initializer list.

Comment: And how could i access the dummy then from inside the function some_func()?

Comment: Apart from inefficiency, your code is perfectly valid. The inefficiency comes from objects being copied unnecessarily.

Comment: @majomere You access it the way you do in the question. Are you having an actual problem or are you just assuming that this can't possibly be correct?

Answer (score 2):

In your case `Dummy` has a default constructor, so you should have no problem doing it the way you did.

You can also use [**member initializer list**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor), as you can see below:

```
Server(string ip__, string port__, Dummy dummy__)
   : ip(ip__), port(port__), dummy(dummy__) 
{}
```

This method will work even if `Dummy` does not have a default constructor.

Afterwards you can use the `dummy` member anywhere in class `Server`. At the moment you did not define any public member in class `Dummy`.
Once you do, you can use: `dummy.<some_public_member_of_Dummy>` throughout `Server`.

Side notes:

1. It will be more efficient to pass arguments to the `Server` constructor by a const refernce, e.g.: `Dummy const & dummy__`.
2. Better to avoid `using namespace std` - see here [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize the data member `dummy` in the [**constructor initializer list**](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/constructor-member-initializer-lists/) of `Server::Server(std::string, std::string, Dummy)` as shown below:

```
class Server{
//other code here
    
Server(string port__, string ip__, Dummy dummy__)
//---------------------------vvvvvvvvvvvvvv----------->initialize dummy in constructor initializer list
    :port(port__), ip(ip__), dummy(dummy__) {
       
    }
};
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/J4mEbCcS4)

Note that your `Dummy` class has no member function named `hello_world` so you cannot call that function on `Dummy` object.